# Fill Column BY Joining T1 and T2

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I need to fill column `ISkeyProduct` by joining table T1 and T2 over `Country` and `Itemcode` (see attachment for tables). The final values in column `iskeyproduct` should be True or False but not NULL.

My code is:

```
Update T1 
Set IsKeyProduct = Case 
                      When t2.ItemCode is not Null Then 1 Else 0 
                   End
From T1 
Left join T2 on t1.ShopCountry = t2.Country
             and t1.ItemCode = case when t2.ItemCode
Where 
    (t1.ItemCode is not Null and t2.ItemCode is not null )
```

Comment: but with this code i get series of "1" and NULL.

Comment: Which one is T1 and which one is T2 in your sample?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: So what is the problem? You got an error? and unexpected result?

Comment: PARDON for bad formated Question: First table in attachment is T1 and lower table is T2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get rid of the second predicate and fix the `JOIN ON` condition:

```
UPDATE T1 
SET IsKeyProduct = CASE WHEN t2.ItemCode IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2
    ON t1.ShopCountry = t2.Country AND t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode
WHERE t1.ItemCode IS NOT NULL
```

This predicate:

```
t2.ItemCode is not null
```

filters out those records for which `IsKeyProduct` should be set to `0`.